# Putting the contents of /dev/urandom into a variable?

Tags: bash, variable, random

This is a follow on from my previous thread :-
[Passing date command into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651412/passing-date-command-into-a-variable)

Ok so effectively I would like /dev/urandom to generate 4 digits for me. And place them into a variable.

Here is an example of my bash script :-

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=0; c<=10; c++))
do
        a="$(tr -dc '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4)"

        echo $a
done
```

The only reason I wish to "Echo" the results is so I can actually see that /dev/urandom has generated 4 digits for me correctly.

For my bash script I wish to make, I need to do this programmatically as I wish to do further operation's on the generated results.

So I need not "Echo" the results. so is `a="$(tr -dc '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4)"`

Actually placing 4 random digits into the variable "a"? when I Echo "a" from my script I just get a hanging console and have to use "CTRL+C" to bring my console back.

All I am trying do is place 4 random digits from /dev/urandom into a variable.

I m a new to bash scripting so all advice welcome and thank you in advanced for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fold` will just fold the infinite stream of digits and thus `a` is being defined indefinitely. You will need to add a terminating command, simplest `head`:

```
 a="$(tr -dc '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4 | head -n1)"
```

Just compare the bahaviour of these two commands

```
tr -dc '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4  
tr -dc '[:digit:]' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 4 | head -n1
```

The first one will show the infinite stream of 4-digit random numbers, while the second will abort after one line.

Comment: Thank you!, Is there anyway I can reward you? I have been stressing over this for a week in my head and googling like crazy. Again a big thank you! 

shanzem@Shanzem-Laptop:~$ ./me2.sh
6833
3491
2564
0628
8361
3693
3398
3753
4049
8340
2090
shanzem@Shanzem-Laptop:~$

Finally got my result.

Comment: @Shanzem just mark it as accepted answer as you did. This is the concept of this community. Be aware that your script overwrites `a` in each run of the loop. For getting it in a matrix, use e.g. `a[i]="$( ... )"` Or simpler skip the loop and run: `a=( $( .... | head -n 10 ) )` and call via `${a[0]}`, `${a[1]}` ... etc. `bash` indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Understood and again thank you so much :).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need security, you can use bash's built-in [`RANDOM`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-RANDOM) variable. To get a random number between 0 and 9999 inclusive, `$((RANDOM % 10000))` gives a small bias towards values less than 767, because the values of `$RANDOM` are uniform in the range [0, 32767]. To get a uniform distribution, and put leading zeros:

```
while a=$((RANDOM + 10000)); ((a <= 39999)); do :; done
a=${a#?}
```

Note again that this is not applicable anywhere security is a concern. The output from `$RANDOM` is not unpredictable.

If you do need security, then `/dev/urandom` is the right place to get random data. Calling `fold` is unnecessary on most current unices: you can grab 4 characters with `head -c`.

```
a=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 0-9 | head -c 4)
```

`head -c` is not POSIX and not present on OpenBSD, but it's present in other BSD and on Linux (both with GNU coreutils and BusyBox).

If you need portability to systems that don't have `head -c`, then `fold -w 4 | head -n 1` is a good replacement that's POSIX standard. Just note that you do need the `head` call, otherwise `fold` will keep outputting lines of 4 digits forever.